# Reading mashabe API using urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, mashape

I have this code to read Mashape.com API in python 2. how can i read it in python 3?

**code**

```
import urllib, urllib2, json
from pprint import pprint

URL = "https://getsentiment.p.mashape.com/"
text = "The food was great, but the service was slow."
params = {'text': text, 'domain': 'retail', 'terms': 1, 'categories': 1,'sentiment': 1, 'annotate': 1}
headers = {'X-Mashape-Key': YOUR_MASHAPE_KEY}

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(URL, urllib.urlencode(params), headers=headers)
response = opener.open(request)
opener.close()

data = json.loads(response.read())
pprint(data)
```

i tried this code but it had following error :

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

URL = "https://getsentiment.p.mashape.com/"
text = "The food was great, but the service was slow."
params = {'text': text, 'domain': 'retail', 'terms': 1, 'categories': 1, 'sentiment': 1, 'annotate': 1}
headers = {'X-Mashape-Key': YOUR_MASHAPE_KEY}

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib.request.Request(URL, urllib.parse.urlencode(params), headers)
response = opener.open(request)
opener.close()

data = json.loads(response.read())
print(data)
```

**error :**

```
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

Comment: Post the problem you are having with python 3, and why you cannot "read it"

Comment: i dont know how to read it , i copied this code from somewhere and i didnt found such a thing for python 3

Comment: Yeah, but what happens when you run this code with python 3?

Comment: looks like urllib2 is changed in python 3

Comment: What line is giving this error?

Comment: in this line : `response = opener.open(request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(URL, urllib.parse.urlencode(params), headers)
```

Try to replace to

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(URL, data, headers)
```

Comment: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 402: Payment Required` hahaha

Comment: Yes, but this is not a code error, is something about your account. The request was successfull, but the server responded the 402 status. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes